# AVG function with multiple conditions and columns in SQL Lite

Tags: sql, sqlite, conditional-statements, average

I figured out how to do avg function with condition/s but I couldn't make it work for my specific need. 
Let's say I'm working with this table called sales_performance

```
  product_ID  sales_period  sales_qty  sales_index  product_sub goal_met
         C12          0001         15           20          D71        Y
         D71          0001         07           09          C12        N
         F20          0001         25           30          C05        Y
         C05          0001         10           15          F20        N
         C12          0002         15           30          C05        Y
         C05          0002         12           06          C12        N
         D71          0002         30           20          F20        Y
         F20          0002         20           15          D71        N
         C12          0003         05           04          F20        N
         F20          0003         40           35          C12        Y
         D71          0003         20           20          C05        Y
         C05          0003         12           10          D71        N
```

I want to calculate a new value called sales_index_goal for product C12. Then, the formula for this value would be:

> average of `sales_index` of product `'C12'` when `Goal_Met = 'Y'` and the `sales_index` of its `sub_product` when `Goal_Met = 'N'` during the sales periods before that one.

So for example if I wanted to calculate sales_index_goal for product `'C12'` for `sales_period` `0003`, it would be calculated as:

> average of (`30`,`20`,`15`) where `30` and `20` are the `sales_index`es of product `'C12'` in sales periods `1` and `2` and `15` is the `sales_index` of Product `'F20'` in sales period `2`.

I'm not having any trouble calculating this value for exact sales periods. However, I'm having a hard time coming up with a query that calculates this value for product `'C12'` for all sales periods. Currently, I have written this query which is not working:

```
SELECT 
    s.*, 
    AVG(CASE 
        WHEN s2.goal_met = "Y" AND s2.product_id = "C2" 
            THEN s2.sales_index 
        WHEN s2.product_id = (
            SELECT s2.product_sub WHERE s2.product_id = "C12"
        ) AND s2.goals_met = "N" 
            THEN s2.sales_index
        ELSE NULL 
    END)
    OVER (
        ORDER BY s.sales_period 
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
    ) AS sales_index_goal
FROM 
    sales_performance s, 
    sales_performance s2
WHERE s.product_id = "C12"
```

I would really appreciate any help on this. Bonus: Calculating this value for all products for all sales periods.

Edit: The below answer works well for calculating sales_index_goal for product C12 however, it doesn't work for product F20 (more detailed reason to why it doesn't work is in my comment below the answer) 
You can see the result of the query for product F20 [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/57g3U2EVa9pt7nph3qRsAh/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this actually needs window functions.

The example below just self-links the table and groups by the C12 products.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales_performance
> (
>  product_ID varchar(3) not null,
>  sales_period varchar(4) not null,
>  sales_qty char(2) not null,
>  sales_index char(2) not null,
>  product_sub char(3) not null,
>  goal_met char(1)  not null,
>  PRIMARY KEY (product_ID, sales_period)
> )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO sales_performance
> (product_ID,sales_period,sales_qty,sales_index,product_sub,goal_met) 
> VALUES
>  ('C12','0001','15','20','D71','Y')
> ,('D71','0001','07','09','C12','N')
> ,('F20','0001','25','30','C05','Y')
> ,('C05','0001','10','15','F20','N')
> ,('C12','0002','15','30','C05','Y')
> ,('C05','0002','12','06','C12','N')
> ,('D71','0002','30','20','F20','Y')
> ,('F20','0002','20','15','D71','N')
> ,('C12','0003','05','04','F20','N')
> ,('F20','0003','40','35','C12','Y')
> ,('D71','0003','20','20','C05','Y')
> ,('C05','0003','12','10','D71','N')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT c12.*, sub.sales_index
> FROM sales_performance c12
> LEFT JOIN sales_performance sub 
>   ON sub.sales_period < c12.sales_period 
>  AND 
>  (
>     (sub.product_ID = c12.product_sub AND sub.goal_met = 'N') OR
>     (sub.product_ID = c12.product_ID AND sub.goal_met = 'Y')
>  )
> WHERE c12.product_id = 'C12'
> ORDER BY c12.product_ID, c12.sales_period, sub.product_ID
> ```
>
> ```
> product_ID | sales_period | sales_qty | sales_index | product_sub | goal_met | sales_index
> :--------- | :----------- | :-------- | :---------- | :---------- | :------- | :----------
> C12        | 0001         | 15        | 20          | D71         | Y        | null       
> C12        | 0002         | 15        | 30          | C05         | Y        | 15         
> C12        | 0002         | 15        | 30          | C05         | Y        | 20         
> C12        | 0003         | 05        | 04          | F20         | N        | 20         
> C12        | 0003         | 05        | 04          | F20         | N        | 30         
> C12        | 0003         | 05        | 04          | F20         | N        | 15
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>  c12.*
>  , ROUND(AVG(sub.sales_index),1) AS sales_index_goal
> FROM sales_performance c12
> LEFT JOIN sales_performance sub 
>   ON sub.sales_period < c12.sales_period 
>  AND 
>  (
>     (sub.product_ID = c12.product_sub AND sub.goal_met = 'N') OR
>     (sub.product_ID = c12.product_ID AND sub.goal_met = 'Y')
>  )
> WHERE c12.product_id = 'C12' 
> GROUP BY c12.product_ID, c12.sales_period
> ORDER BY c12.product_ID, c12.sales_period;
> ```
>
> ```
> product_ID | sales_period | sales_qty | sales_index | product_sub | goal_met | sales_index_goal
> :--------- | :----------- | :-------- | :---------- | :---------- | :------- | :---------------
> C12        | 0001         | 15        | 20          | D71         | Y        | null            
> C12        | 0002         | 15        | 30          | C05         | Y        | 17.5            
> C12        | 0003         | 05        | 04          | F20         | N        | 21.7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=cff0f7c29d9b3675a9c51a10443de544)*

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time to answer but the values except for sales period 0003 are not what I'm looking for. The value should be NULL for the first period and 17.5 for the second case

Comment: @memokerobi Just changing the `<=` to `<` seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Using window function is a good place to start. One problem lies in the fact that you want to average values that come from different columns, and that could have a different count of occurences.

I think that you need to break the calculation down to compute the average: sum the values, and divide that by the sum of occurences.

Consider:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        s.*,
        (
            0.0 + 
            COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN goal_met = 'Y' THEN sales_index END) OVER(
                PARTITION BY product_id 
                ORDER BY sales_period 
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
            ), 0)
            + COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN goal_met = 'N' THEN sales_index END) OVER(
                PARTITION BY product_sub 
                ORDER BY sales_period 
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
            ), 0)
        ) / (
            COALESCE(SUM(goal_met = 'Y') OVER(
                PARTITION BY product_id 
                ORDER BY sales_period 
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
            ), 0)
            + COALESCE(SUM(goal_met = 'N') OVER(
                PARTITION BY product_sub 
                ORDER BY sales_period 
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
            ), 0)
        ) AS sales_index_goal
    FROM sales_performance s
) x WHERE product_ID = 'C12'
```

In **[this DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/57g3U2EVa9pt7nph3qRsAh/0)**, with your sample data, this returns:

```
| product_ID | sales_period | sales_qty | sales_index | product_sub | goal_met | sales_index_goal   |
| ---------- | ------------ | --------- | ----------- | ----------- | -------- | ------------------ |
| C12        | 1            | 15        | 20          | D71         | Y        |                    |
| C12        | 2            | 15        | 30          | C05         | Y        | 20                 |
| C12        | 3            | 5         | 4           | F20         | N        | 21.666666666666668 |
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This mainly worked but there was one problem. Imagine I am trying to calculate the sales_index_goal value for F20 instead of C12 in sales period 0003. The returned value should be 30 as there is only one occurrence of a (F20 and Y) or (C12 and N). However, instead of returning 0 for C12 and N, the code returns sales index of the product_sub of C12 in the cases where C12's goal met = Y. So it returns the sales index of D71 in period 0001 and C05 in period 0002. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: actually the the sales_index_goal for C12 on the second case should be 17.5 and not 20, I don't know if it is counting the sales_index of product C05 for period 0001.